# When to use \...\m in regular expressions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

If I have this string:

st = "The important thing is not to stop questioning.

Curiosity has its own reason for existing.

Never lose a holy curiosity."

and I want to match "Curiosity" using a regular expression, can I use

```
/Curiosity/m === st
```

When do you typically make use of \...\m ?

Thank you very much, I appreciate it!

Comment: Your question is doubly unclear: 1.) What does this have to do with [tag:ruby-on-rals]? 2.) What flavor of [tag:regex] are you talking about? My first guess was [tag:Ruby] 2 / [tag:Onigmo], but that doesn't have `\m`, [it only has `\M`](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE#L30-L31). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a typo in my question. I was asking about /.../m

Comment: Then it might be a good idea to edit your question to remove the multiple(!!!) references to `\m`.

Comment: Thank you @JörgWMittag, I just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need it for your example case. `m` is a modifier that allows the dot (that means by default any character except the newline) to match also newlines.

Note that this meaning of the m modifier is specific to ruby and its regex engine, in other languages, that uses other regex engines, the modifer m has a different meaning.

Examples:

`/a.*b/` matches `"a#123opi[b"`

but it doesn't match `"a#123
opi[b"`

because by default the dot `.` doesn't match a newline.

`/a.*b/m` does because the m modifier changes the meaning of the dot and allows it to match newlines.

Comment: Oh, I see, I think I've misunderstood the usage of m, I thought it was used when the user entered a multiline input. You're right, just tried /Curiosity/ === st in http://rubular.com/ and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JoanaB: note that rubular is a good tool for ruby developers and gives a lot of informations about regex for this language.

Comment: True, I just discovered it and it seems very useful. Thank you very much for your help, and especially for the example.